# How to refer to https with javascript

Tags: javascript, http, https

I need my page to direct people to to the https part of the website only on the 3rd step of this reservation system i have i don't  want the whole website to be running on https.

basically i own a car rental company and would like the section of the information where people fill to be on a https server which i already have the certificate and its on my website working

this code here is on the page that i would like for them to click on and it takes them to the other page but with https:
how can i make this javascript code output an https link instead of the link its outputting right now

```
<div class="button" style=""><a href="javascript:processFeesPage();"> <?php l_e("Click to continue"); ?></a></div>
```

basically

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function processFeesPage()
        {
            var feeschart;
            feeschart = MM_findObj('feeschart');
            objtotaltotaltax = MM_findObj('totaltotaltax');
            // save with Ajax, cleaning a bit the code and go to step-4 (customer details)
            var http_request =  getRequestAjax();
            http_request.open('POST','<?php echo VIRTUAL_ROOT; ?>scripts/saveformajax.php', false);      
            var parameters = '';
            parameters = encodeParam('rentalitems',feeschart.innerHTML);
            parameters = parameters + "&" + encodeParam('totalcost',objtotaltotaltax.innerHTML);
            parameters = parameters + "&" + encodeParam('pricereturn','<?php echo $pricereturn; ?>');
            for (var i in selected_values)
                parameters = parameters + "&" + encodeParam(i,""+selected_values[i]);
            http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=iso-8859-1;");
            http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-Encoding", "iso-8859-1");
            http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", parameters.length);
            http_request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
            http_request.send(parameters);
            document.location= './step-4';
        }
      </script>
```

Comment: Please post your `processFeesPage()` function

Comment: I think you might be missing some of the question at the end?

Comment: so what i want it to do is just make the click button go to the https page im pretty sure it can be done i been trying forever :(

Comment: http://servername.com/step-4  thats what it takes me to right now when i click click to continue

Comment: For that you will either have to use a absolute URL as your `http_request.open()` argument or redirect to https on that particular page.

Comment: If you use a redirect make sure all resources on that page are loaded through the https channel to prevent loading errors.

Comment: -ht tp: //rentacar.com/step-4 thats what it opens click to continue but what i would like for it to open is -htt ps: //rentacar.com/step-4

Comment: Do you even read the comments? I also get the feeling you are not understanding the code you posted and wishes that we fix it for you.

Comment: The questioner lacks understanding of posted code so this question is unlikely to be answered.

Comment: im reading the comments the problem is i cant understand them sorry and yes i understand the code and all it does all im wanting for it to do is just go to https on step 4 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
document.location= './step-4';
```

is using the **current context** to generate the entire url: http://rentacar.com/step4

Because you now want to switch to a new `protocol (https)` you can't use the `.` shortcut you're currently using.

You can either put in the full path:

```
document.location= 'https://rentacar.com/step4'
```

or you can try to work it out programmatically. For example:

```
var currentUrl = 'http://' + window.location.hostname + '/step4'
```